# Moving IMAP mail to Gmail and retaining correct times

Tags: email, gmail, imap, procmail

I am trying to use gmail to manage mail from an email account I have that is imap only.  My strategy was to use ([getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) to retrieve mail from the server and pass it through to procmail for forwarding.

This almost works.  It successfully retrieves the mail and forwards it on to my gmail account.  What it does not do it keep the appropriate "sent" times.  That is, an email that I received 3 months ago shows up as me having received it at the time it was forwarded.

So the question is, how can I get these mails forwarded and have their original sent times honored?

Comment: Do you have more information on how you've setup getmail and procmail. I'm having a hard time configuring this.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to enable imap in your gmail account and use imapsync:

http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync/

Comment: This works for the first sync, but it takes too long to be a solution for constant use.  I'd like to have something that can poll my account every ten minutes or so and send any new mails to the other account.

Comment: Fetchmail should be capable to transfer only "new" messages. So if you initially transfer the old ones using imapsync once and then use fetchmail, say every 2 minutes, the copied or moved mail's time stamp should not differ much.